# issue on MS SQL managament studio 2005..?

Tags: installation, sql-server, sql-server-2005

am having MS SQL 2005 developer edition.

And when am trying to install it(MS SQL 2005) on my windows XP SP2 system- am not getting MS SQL management studio..?/

what will be the issue..??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed/selected the Client Tools when doing the initial install, you can also select them if you do a repair install

Comment: yup i had selected the option "management tools" ion "client tools"
..
it gives me error --> ADD_LOCAL already exists..!!